# Why the dual to $c_0$ is $l^1$ and the space of sequences with bounded partial sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

The dual to $c_0$ is $l^1$, but if $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in c_0$, than according to Dirichlet's test
$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-1)^nx_n$ converges. But $\{(-1)^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\notin l^1$. So why is the dual space $l^1$ and not space of sequences with bounded partial sums, as $\{(-1)^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is?

I'd prefer a rather intuitive explanation to a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your convergence statement is false, because Dirichlet's test assumes monotonicity. Indeed $x_n=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ is in $c_0$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x_n = +\infty$.